# icons are not showing after clicking close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm making an application in Next.js in which after clicking on the hamburger (mobile mode) the icons of a Slide disappear and after clicking close they reappear.

The application has the following structure

[image: structure]

The hamburger function is inside `Navbar.js` and has the following code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/dist/client/link";
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import useLocalStorageState from 'use-local-storage-state'
import {
    AiFillHome,
  } from "react-icons/ai"

function Nav() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useLocalStorageState('isMobile', false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);


  function process(){
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    setIsMobile(true);
}

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-10 top-0">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <div className="cursor-pointer flex-shrink-0">
              
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:block">
                <div className="ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-4">
                <div className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md  ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                    <AiFillHome className="text-gray-300 mr-0" />
                  <Link
                   to="/home" href="/" 
                    className=" hover:text-white  text-white pr-3 py-2text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Home
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                  <a
                    href="SectorA"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2  text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector A
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                  <a
                    href="SectorB"
                    className="text-gray-300  hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector A
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                 
                  <a
                    href="SectorC"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector C
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                
                  <a
                    href="SectorD"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector D
                  </a>
                </div>
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={() => process()}
                type="button"
                className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                aria-controls="mobile-menu"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {!isOpen ? (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    />
                  </svg>
                ) : (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          show={isOpen}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          {(ref) => (
            <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
              <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                <Link
                   to="/home" href="/"
                  
                ><p 
                className="cursor-pointer text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"> 
                  Home
                </p>
                </Link>

                <a
                  href="SectorA"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector A
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorB"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector B
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorC"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector C
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorD"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector D
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </nav>


    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

After changing state (isMobile) `<Arrows/>` and `<Dots/>` disappear and reappear. Below is the code of `Slider.js` where are `<Arrows/>` and `<Dots/>`.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./Slider.module.scss";
import Dots from './dots'
import Arrows from './Arrows'
import useLocalStorageState from 'use-local-storage-state'

function Slider() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useLocalStorageState('isMobile', false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    
  
  
const initialSlides = [
  {
    description: <p>This is the description of slide one Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quos quas, voluptatum nesciunt illum exercitationem.</p>,
    Image: "/images/imagem_youtube.png",
    button: <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 1</button>
  },
  {
    description: 4,
    Image: '/images/imagem_youtube.png',
    button: <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 4</button>
  },
];

const len = initialSlides.length - 1;



  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.slider}>
          {!isMobile &&   <Arrows    
          nextSlide={ () => 
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1)        
          }   
          prevSlide={ () => 
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex < 1 ? len : activeIndex - 1)       
          }
          />}
        
        {initialSlides.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
          <div
            className={index === activeIndex ? "slide_current" : "slide"}
            key={index}
          >
          {index === activeIndex && (
            <div>
                <img src={slide.Image} alt="slide" className={styles.image} />
                <div className={styles.content}>
                  <p>{slide.description}</p>
                  <hr />
                  <p>{slide.button}</p>
                </div>
                {!isMobile &&  <Dots
                        activeIndex={activeIndex}
                        initialSlides={initialSlides}
                        onclick={(activeIndex) => setActiveIndex(activeIndex)}
                      />}
                </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
    })}   
   

    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

The problem is when I click on the hamburger to disappear the icons they disappear but when I click to close the hamburger they do not reappear. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: *Something* should probably call `setIsMobile(false);` to "reset" the `isMobile` value so the arrows and dots get rendered again. Where is a "click to close the hamburger" at in your code snippet?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of a way to do this but I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the `process` handler is what is toggling states. Use a functional state update to toggle/"flip" the boolean state values.

```
function process() {
  setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen);
  setIsMobile(isMobile => !isMobile);
}
```

### Update

Since it has been determined the main purpose is to share an `isOpen` state between the `Navbar` and `Slider` components, one way to accomplish this is to create and use a React Context.

Create a `NavbarContext` file with a context, custom hook, and a provider component.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import useLocalStorageState from "use-local-storage-state";

export const NavbarContext = createContext({
  isOpen: false,
  setIsOpen: () => {}
});

export const useNavbarContext = () => useContext(NavbarContext);

const NavbarContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useLocalStorageState("isOpen", {
    defaultValue: false,
    ssr: false
  });

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider value={{ isOpen, setIsOpen }}>
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NavbarContextProvider;
```

Wrap the page/ui with the `NavbarContextProvider` component.

```
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import NavbarContextProvider from "../components/NavbarContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <NavbarContextProvider>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </NavbarContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Import and use the `useNavbarContext` hook.

```
import { useNavbarContext } from "./NavbarContext";

function Nav() {
  const { isOpen, setIsOpen } = useNavbarContext();

  function process() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  return ....
}
```

...

```
import { useNavbarContext } from "../NavbarContext";

function Slider() {
  const { isOpen } = useNavbarContext();

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const initialSlides = [...];

  const len = initialSlides.length - 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.slider}>
      {!isOpen && (
        <Arrows
          nextSlide={() =>
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1)
          }
          prevSlide={() =>
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex < 1 ? len : activeIndex - 1)
          }
        />
      )}

      {initialSlides.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={index === activeIndex ? "slide_current" : "slide"}
            key={index}
          >
            {index === activeIndex && (
              <div>
                ...
                {!isOpen && (
                  <Dots
                    activeIndex={activeIndex}
                    initialSlides={initialSlides}
                    onclick={(activeIndex) => setActiveIndex(activeIndex)}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I kept the `useLocalStorageState` hook usage in the context so its state value is still persisted/initialized to/from localStorage. Page reloads will act consistently now between the two components.

[image: Edit icons-are-not-showing-after-clicking-close]